# Pacemaker between Centos 5 and Centos 6

Tags: linux, pacemaker, corosync

I'm having some troubles when configuring pacemaker+corosync between Centos 5 and Centos 6. Here is ouput of crm_mon:

On node1:

```
Last updated: Sun Jul 21 19:02:21 2013
Last change: Sun Jul 21 18:14:48 2013 via crmd on svr077-53149.localdomain
Stack: openais
Current DC: svr077-53149.localdomain - partition WITHOUT quorum
Version: 1.1.8-2.el5-394e906
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
1 Resources configured.


Online: [ svr077-53149.localdomain ]
OFFLINE: [ svr423L-2737.localdomain ]

Crond   (lsb:crond):    Started svr077-53149.localdomain
```

On node2:

```
Last updated: Sun Jul 21 19:03:40 2013
Last change: Sun Jul 21 18:14:56 2013
Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
Current DC: NONE
1 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
0 Resources configured.


ONLINE: [ svr423L-2737.localdomain ]
```

Here is my [corosync log](http://pastebin.com/KRrsm3PW)

My question is:

- Why each node has their own DC, node1 detects two nodes while node2
  show only one?
- What can be problem make two node can't join cluster?
- Can we make pacemaker+corosync between Centos 5 and
  Centos 6?

Here is my software version in two node:

```
Node1:

 - Corosync version 1.4.3 
 - Pacemaker version 1.1.8-2.el5 
 - Centos release 5.8 (Final)
```

And

```
Node2:
 - Corosync version 1.4.1
 - Pacemaker version 1.1.8-7.el6
 - Centos release 6.4 (Final)
```

**UPDATE**
When I configured the first time, everything worked ok. After I shutdown node 1, turn on it to test failover case, this problem occured.

Comment: what about settings of firewall/selinux on each of the nodes?

Comment: @ALex_hha: they are disabled. You can see in log file that the communication between two node is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multicast, then check your igmp support in your switch and in your cluster hosts check the corosync membershit status

corosync-cfgtool -s
corosync-cmapctl | grep mem

Thanks

Comment: The first time I config, everything works fine. When I shutdown one node to test failover case, the problem occurs.